# How to disable altering SQL Server tables?

Tags: sql, permissions, sql-server-2016

I have many SQL Server login users created in a database, and I want some users NOT to be allowed to alter tables (such as adding column name, changing data type, etc..) for all tables. Not specific tables.

Is there any way can we do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. There are various database level roles that control this. Have you looked in the security documentation yet? What current roles do they have? What are they allowed to do?

Comment: You should just change the roles of the user to `db_datawriter` and `db_datareader`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this via assigning a particular role to that user.You can use existing role if your need suite this or you can create custom role according to your need.

Here you can know about [database level roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/authentication-access/database-level-roles?view=sql-server-ver15).
Here is a guide to [create custom role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-role-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: we do not want to change in role level. We would like to deny ALTER tables for specific user who is currently with other user in same role.

Comment: @VIC78 then you have to revoke ALTER table privilege for all table for that user

Comment: of course, I tried this...    REVOKE ALTER ON dbo.AST_Activity FROM TestUser

Comment: it work but I can't run 100s of line with different table name

Comment: so is there any script can do ?

Comment: You can query to get all tables and then iterate that list and dynamically build query to revoke privilege for each table and then execute the query via EXECUTE command

Comment: I tried REVOKE ALTER ON dbo.AST_Activity FROM TestUser single query. It work

Comment: but when I run this in script, not working